# mysql using filesort instead of index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE x >= 500 AND x < 5000 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,50
```

I have index: x, date - Btree

Why is this query using index and filesort, if I have index on both values.

x= integer
date = date

tyble type = myisam

explain:

```
ID: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: d
type: range
possible_keys: sort
key: sort
key_len: 2
ref: null
rows: 198
extra: using index condition; using filesort
```

Comment: Please post the `EXPLAIN ...` output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query is using filesort because it is a range query. Filesort would desappear if the query used exact equation.

But you probably know that [**filesort** is actualy a misname](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/) and has actually no relation to files.

Comment: The link you included does not suggest so.

Comment: @arjreal, does not suggest what?

Comment: `First of all, this is Using temporary. Secondly, temporary tables may go to disk if they are too big, but EXPLAIN doesn’t show that. (If I interview you, I might ask you what “too big” means, or I might ask you the other reason temporary tables go to disk!)`

Answer (score 3):

From the reference -

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY,
>   although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE
>   clause. These cases include the following:
>
> The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the
>   ORDER BY:  SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key2=constant ORDER BY key1;

Try to add index INDEX (`date`, x).

Comment: Nope, doesn't help. But thanx for explaining to me.